# Heat equation separation of variables with different boundary conditions

Tags: partial-differential-equations

I need to solve the following heat equation using separation of variables

$
\left\{\begin{matrix}
u_{t}=c^{2}u_{xx} \; \; ,0<x<L,  t>0 \\ 
u(0,t)= 0 \\ 
u_{x}(L,t)=0 \\
u(x,0)=f(x) 
\end{matrix}\right.
$

So far I've got:

$
X''-kX=0 \\
T'-c^{2}kT=0
$

But I'm not sure how to apply the boundaries to this problem and arrive at a general solution.

Any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

Write $k=-\lambda^2$.  Then you can write

$$X(x) = A \cos{\lambda x} + B \sin{\lambda x}$$

$$X(0) = 0 \implies A \cos{0} + B \sin{0} = A = 0$$

$$X'(L) = 0 \implies B \lambda \cos{\lambda L} = 0 \implies \lambda L = (n+1/2) \pi$$

where $n \in \mathbb{Z}$.  So set $\lambda_n = (n+1/2) \pi/L$ is an eigenvalue of the operator, with corresponding eigenfunction

$$X_n(x) = \sin{\left [ \left (n+\frac{1}{2}\right) \frac{\pi x}{L} \right ]}$$

ignoring the scale factor $B$.

For the $T$ equation, we have

$$T_n(t) = B_n e^{-\lambda_n^2 c^2 t}$$

Using the initial condition and the eigenvalues, we then have the following expansion for the general solution:

$$u(x,t) = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} B_n \sin{\left [ \left (n+\frac{1}{2}\right) \frac{\pi x}{L} \right ]} e^{-\frac{(n+1/2)^2 \pi^2 c^2 t}{L^2} }$$

$$u(x,0) = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} B_n \sin{\left [ \left (n+\frac{1}{2}\right) \frac{\pi x}{L} \right ]} = f(x)$$

The $B_n$ are then Fourier coefficients:

$$\begin{align}B_n &= \frac{\displaystyle \int_0^{L} dx \: f(x) \sin{\left [ \left (n+\frac{1}{2}\right) \frac{\pi x}{L} \right ]}}{\displaystyle \int_0^{L} dx \: \sin^2{\left [ \left (n+\frac{1}{2}\right) \frac{\pi x}{L} \right ]}}\\ &= \frac{2}{L} \int_0^{L} dx \: f(x) \sin{\left [ \left (n+\frac{1}{2}\right) \frac{\pi x}{L} \right ]}\end{align}$$

Comment: I'm a little confused on where the Bn coefficient calculation came from, any insight?

Comment: @chrisguuren: orthogonality of the eigenfuctions allows us to sift the one particular coefficient we want, namely, $B_n$.  So we multiply the sum by a particular eigenfunction and integrate over $[0,L]$; the orthogonality means that only that particular eigenfunction has a nonzero integral.